# How to work with Database over SOAP in Django?

Tags: python, django, soap, django-models, suds

Currently I have a Django project, let's call it Backend. There is a folder api and there I have this resource declared using Django-Tastypie:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization
from tastypie.cache import SimpleCache
from tastypie.throttle import CacheDBThrottle

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        cache = SimpleCache()
        throttle = CacheDBThrottle()

        filtering = {
            'username' : ALL,
            'date_joined' : ['gt','lt','gte','lte','range']        
        }
```

With proper routing rules in place, if I access an URL like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user?format=json`, I am supposed to get back some info on users in json format, but from my local database. I do not want to use any local database, except maybe for testing with some dummy data. I want such a get request to result in a SOAP request to a certain remote server with my logged in session's username and password.

I already have a standalone Python application, where I can perform a SOAP request and get a SOAP response back using [SUDS](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) and pre-downloaded WSDL files. Now I want to include this functionality in my Dhango project in such a way, that I change the settings in settings.py in the project, but I do not have to modify the applications inside the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own [Custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-inheritance) that use your standalone Python application.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer is just too scanty. I can see examples, where manager has been overriden or explicitly specified inside the model. But I do not want to do that. I want to be able to switch database/backend using some project settings, so that the Django applications are always untouched, irrespective of the database being used.

Comment: May be that you need is to define your own database backend. This backend will interact with your python application. You can see examples in "Using a 3rd-party database backend" Django documentation section. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend

Comment: I have gone through the official Django pages already. Those are SQL backends, and I cannot imagine from that how to write a SOAP backend. I do not want a real database backend. I want to send and receive SOAP messages.

Comment: Can you paste one case of use for your application? I don't understand the problem to solve...

Comment: I have modified the question. Does this help?

Comment: Ok. I now understand better the problem. I propose you a possible solution in following answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [tastypie documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#adding-to-the-api). Adding this code to your urls.py should work:

```
from tastypie.api import Api
from my_app.api.resources import UserResource

v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(UserResource())

#old urlpatterns here

urlpatterns += patterns('',
  (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
)
```

Comment: This is already in my urls, and it works just fine, but with local database. I want to use a web service through SOAP instead. That was the original problem.